# Open NotePad in mys form on top

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, notepad, showdialog

Can you hel me please to open an application (notepad) on top my form ?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process N = new Process.Start(@"notepad.exe");
        N.ShowDialog(this);
    }
```

I try this but is not correctly.
So, how can i open notepad.exe or word.exe on top my form as ShowDialog please ?

Cordialy

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SetForegroundWindow function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx).

Declare `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` and use

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void SetNotepadAsForegroundApp()
{
    Process N = new Process.Start(@"notepad.exe");
    SetForegroundWindow(N.MainWindowHandle);
}
```